# Add Column with each cell to compare adjacent cell with above cells of adjacent column

Tags: python-3.x

I am novice yet to python,

My dataframe has two columns and many rows:

```
Customer_Acquired_Date|Customer_mobile_number
1/20/2017|100000001
2/2/2017|100000002
2/12/2017|100000001
2/23/2017|100000004
3/1/2017|100000005
3/7/2017|100000004
```

I want to add a column called "RepeatOrNew"
Each cell in this new column will look for customer mobile number in the above cells of adjacent column. If it exist then type "Repeat", if it doesn't exist then type "New".

Output:

```
Customer_Acquired_Date|Customer_mobile_number|RepeatOrNew
1/20/2017|100000001|New
2/2/2017|100000002|New
2/12/2017|100000001|Repeat
2/23/2017|100000004|New
3/1/2017|100000005|New
3/7/2017|100000004|Repeat
```

I am completely blank where to start. Please assist.

Thanks,
Ninad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `grouping`, the `cumcount` method of a `GroupBy` and numpy's `where` function to get your desired output. The following should constitute a decent starting point:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO


data_stream = StringIO("""Customer_Acquired_Date|Customer_mobile_number
1/20/2017|100000001
2/2/2017|100000002
2/12/2017|100000001
2/23/2017|100000004
3/1/2017|100000005
3/7/2017|100000004""")

customers = pd.read_table(data_stream, sep="|", header=0)


counter = customers.groupby('Customer_mobile_number').cumcount()
customers['RepeatOrNew'] = np.where(counter == 0, 'New','Repeat')
```

Or a one-liner:

```
customers['RepeatOrNew'] = customers.groupby('Customer_mobile_number').cumcount().apply(lambda x: 'New' if x == 0 else 'Repeat')
```

Should yield something like:

```
  Customer_Acquired_Date  Customer_mobile_number RepeatOrNew
0              1/20/2017               100000001         New
1               2/2/2017               100000002         New
2              2/12/2017               100000001      Repeat
3              2/23/2017               100000004         New
4               3/1/2017               100000005         New
5               3/7/2017               100000004      Repeat
```

I hope this proves useful.